# Setting property to be null again within Class

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a class called *MapFilter*, which conditionally creates an array of objects.

When the class is created, the property named `postCodeFilter` is automatically set to be `null`.  When using the class with this initial null value the logic works fine:

```
MapFilter.prototype.filterByPostcode = function(res){

    var newRes = [];

    console.log(this.postcodeFilter);
    if(typeof this.postcodeFilter !== 'undefined') {

        for( var i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ) {

            if(res[i].postcode == this.postCodeFilter) {

                newRes.push(res[i]);

            }

        }   

    } else {

        newRes = res.slice();

    } 

    return newRes;

};
```

When it is initially running the method that calls this method, it will run what is in the else block

HOWEVER

after setting a value for `postcodeFilter` I can not set it back to be `null` or `undefined` again.

I have tried the following approaches, with no success

```
delete this.serviceFilter;
this.serviceFilter = null;
this.serviceFilter = undefined;
```

I have tried doing the same on the instance of the `MapFilter` class to no avail

How do I reset a property of a class to be `null` or `undefined` again?

Comment: beyond the code that attempts to delete/set null the `serviceFilter` property, can you edit you post to include code that uses/sets it? Or did you intend to clear a different property (e.g. `postcodeFilter`)?

Comment: Notice that testing for `typeof` to be `undefined`, it will not catch `null` values.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the non-working code. All the assignments you presented should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function MapFilter (){
      this.postcodeFilter=null
    }
    
    MapFilter.prototype.filterByPostcode = function(){

    console.log(this.postcodeFilter);
    if(this.postcodeFilter !== null) {

      console.log('is bull')

       

    } else {
        console.log('is null')

    } 

}

var test = new MapFilter()

test.filterByPostcode()
test.postcodeFilter='bull'
test.filterByPostcode()
```

dont use `type of null` it will not return `null`

> if you calling prototype inside function

dont call with `this.postcodeFilter` try use instance name like `test.postcodeFilter`